# How to prevent route change using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There's a certain page in my React app that I would like to prevent the user from leaving if the form is dirty.

In my react-routes, I am using the onLeave prop like this:

```
<Route path="dependent" component={DependentDetails} onLeave={checkForm}/>
```

And my `onLeave` is:

```
const checkForm = (nextState, replace, cb) => {
  if (form.IsDirty) {
    console.log('Leaving so soon?');
    // I would like to stay on the same page somehow...
  }
};
```

Is there a way to prevent the new route from firing and keep the user on the same page?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Hi @PhilVarg, I'm using react-router@2.0.1 and react-router-redux@4.0.2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is too late but according to the [`React Router Documentation`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions) you can use `preventing transition` with helping of `<prompt>` component.

```
  <Prompt
      when={isBlocking}
      message={location =>
        `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
      }
    />
```

if `isBlocking` equal to `true` it shows a message. for more information you can read the documentation.

Comment: @vsync [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Prompt.md#when-bool)  

Instead of conditionally rendering a <Prompt> behind a guard, you can always render it but pass when={true} or when={false} to prevent or allow navigation accordingly.

Comment: The `message` prop can also be a function that returns true or false, not just a string. This can help avoid the browser alert in favor of a custom modal or something else

Comment: This is no longer the case with Router v6, unfortunately as Prompt was removed.

Answer (score 9):

react-router v6 no longer supports the Prompt component (they say that they hope to add it back once they have an acceptable implementation).  However, react-router makes use of the [history](https://github.com/remix-run/history/) package which offers the following [example](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/dev/docs/blocking-transitions.md) for how to block transitions.

Note that to actually make this work in react router you have to replace the createBrowserHistory call with some hackery to make sure you are using the same history object as react router (see bottom of answer).

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();
let unblock = history.block((tx) => {
  // Navigation was blocked! Let's show a confirmation dialog
  // so the user can decide if they actually want to navigate
  // away and discard changes they've made in the current page.
  let url = tx.location.pathname;
  if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you want to go to ${url}?`)) {
    // Unblock the navigation.
    unblock();

    // Retry the transition.
    tx.retry();
  }
```

You'll need to put this inside the appropriate useEffect hook and build the rest of the functionality that would have otherwise been provided by prompt.  Note that this will also produce an (uncustomizable) warning if the user tries to navigate away but closing the tab or refreshing the page indicating that unsaved work may not be saved.

Please read the linked page as there are some drawbacks to using this functionality.  Specifically, it adds an event listener to the beforeunload event which makes the page [ineligible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) for the bfcache in firefox (though the code attempts to deregister the handler if the navigation is cancelled I'm not sure this restores salvageable status) I presume it's these issues which caused react-router to disable the Prompt component.

**WARNING** to access history in React Router 6 you need to follow something like the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70095819/351049) which is a bit of a hack.  Initially, I assumed that you could just use createBrowserHistory to access the history object as that code is illustrated in the react router documentation but (a bit confusingly imo) it was intended only to illustrate the idea of what the history does.

Answer (score 7):

I think the recommended approach has changed since Lazarev's answer, since his linked example is no longer currently in the `examples` folder.  Instead, I think you should follow [this example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/confirming-navigation/app.js#L31) by defining:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(
    this.props.route,
    this.routerWillLeave
  )
},
```

And then define `routerWillLeave` to be a function that returns a string which will appear in a confirmation alert.

**UPDATE**

The previous link is now outdated and unavailable. In newer versions of React Router it appears there is a new component `Prompt` that can be used to cancel/control navigation. See [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)

Comment: here is an example usingreact-router-dom Prompt: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions

Comment: Looks like the latest version of `react-router-dom` uses a component called `Prompt`. You can see an [example here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions)

Answer (score 3):

We're using React Router V5, and our site needed a custom prompt message to show up, and [this medium article](https://michaelchan-13570.medium.com/using-react-router-v4-prompt-with-custom-modal-component-ca839f5faf39) helped me understand how that was possible

TLDR: the `<Prompt/>` component from react-router-dom can accept a function as the message prop, and if that function returns `true` you'll continue in the navigation, and if `false` the navigation will be blocked

Comment: Above all the answers this one was soo good. It is so easy to understand and required lesser code to carry out the logic.

Comment: That medium article is a gem. Kudos! The link to live example from React Router is [here.](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

React-router api provides a [`Transition`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/e8a16efaddc272f286cce2a1735753079a2d33a7/docs/api/components/RouteHandler.md#willtransitionfromtransition-component-callback) object for such cases, you can create a hook in a `willTransitionTo` lifecycle method of the component, you are using. Something like (code taken from react-router [examples](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/e8a16efaddc272f286cce2a1735753079a2d33a7/examples/transitions/app.js) on the github):

```
var Form = React.createClass({

  mixins: [ Router.Navigation ],

  statics: {
    willTransitionFrom: function (transition, element) {
      if (element.refs.userInput.getDOMNode().value !== '') {
        if (!confirm('You have unsaved information, are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
          transition.abort();
        }
      }
    }
  },

  handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.refs.userInput.getDOMNode().value = '';
    this.transitionTo('/');
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>Click the dashboard link with text in the input.</p>
          <input type="text" ref="userInput" defaultValue="ohai" />
          <button type="submit">Go</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank Lazarev, but in my code example, is there no way to just "stay on the page" and not go to the selected route?

Comment: you wouldnt do it from the routes page, you would do it from your component, adding a `willTransitionFrom` hook, and checking if your form is dirty from there calling `transition.abort()` if it is

Comment: I think you can't do it. Even if you can, it seems to be a bad approach, because even none of arguments are passed to `onLeave` event. If I'm not mistaken, `onLeave` most commonly is used for animations. By the way how do are you going to access `form`?